# Проблема при верстке

Tags: css, css3, html5, scss

Я начинающая верстальщица и при верстке макета у меня возникло две проблемы:

1. Косые тени для картинок(как их сделать?)
2. Линия под наклоном[![введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Cами блоки необычной формы(как их сделать?)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я его делал уже тыщу лет назад: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OKbaVr но где то у меня есть и на html css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дальше играть медиа запросами и при каких то разрешениях менять padding

На самом деле там не сложно

Рисуем тот самый косой компонент и вставляем его между блоками ну вот и весь фокус

В SVG два path и пот ними лежит rect тёмно-зелёного цвета

Цвет нижнего path совпадает с фоном нижнего блока

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.one {
  background: #5fc18b;
}

.two {
  background: #45a36f;
}

.block {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  width: 400px;
}

.svg-container {
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block one">
  <div class="item">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat mollitia error accusamus voluptas omnis distinctio itaque numquam cumque atque, quos voluptatibus vitae ipsam officiis deleniti illum non sed ex impedit?
  </div>
</div>

<div class="svg-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect width="100%" height="99%"  x="0" y="0" fill="darkgreen" />
    <path d="M0,0,20,0,0,6z" fill="#5fc18b"/>
    <path d="M0,6,20,6,20,0.24z" fill="#45a36f"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="block two">
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum eaque vero vel, quidem, optio rem autem eum consequuntur quasi ut ad, adipisci alias sapiente? Illum dolorem officia veniam est possimus.
  </div>
</div>
```